# How to make a text file to be the "database" in a Spring Rest Application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

I´m developing a Jokenpo Game using React with Spring Rest, but I can´t have a database to store all the information needed(create and delete moves, create and delete players).

I don´t know the best practice of development, or if there is some design pattern on how to store that kind of information. I know there is the folder src/main/resources where maybe I can store a text file there and thought about on the startup of the api it loads that file with the begin of the game, maybe, and after changing it during the game.

Trying to be more clear: I just would like to know the simplest way of storing information without being a database inside of a Spring Rest application. I really appreciate any helps. Thanks.

Comment: You don't store the text file itself but its content (binary representation). Search out how to store a BLOB.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). It's a very light database library that you can include as a dependency of your Spring application, It doesn't require a separate database server to run, and the entire database is stored in a single file, that you can choose where to store in the connection string.

It offers the flexibility of a standard database, so you can use Spring Data / JPA to access the data. It has some limitations compared with robust databases like MySQL, specially related with concurrent writes that you should investigate and be aware of. Usually it works very well for small applications or embedded applications.

Comment: Another alternative is h2. It can work as an in-memory or file based relational database and is also supported by spring data. See https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/